# TwoLineListItem

Tags: android, android-layout

Please take a look at the screenshot on the left:

http://bit.ly/a4F5Ln

Could anyone tell me what view components are those with texts Notebook and Selected tags? Could it be TwoLineListItem? Any examples using it?

Basically, I'd like to replace Spinner components with something similar.

Thanks!

EDIT: Hmmm... how to reply to an answer?

Anyway, yes, thanks, this looks like a ListPreference. Does that mean that I can have a ListPreference in any Activity, or that sample I posted is actually PreferenceActivity with other, non-preference views?

Comment: Suspect it's a PreferenceActivity with some custom preference types...

Comment: Yes, it does look so. I'll investigate and report back here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look like [`ListPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) to me...

[image]